# Why does this monad not compile

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, .net-4.6

Why does this monad not compile? Commented row works fine. Adding `where U : class` makes it compile but that adds restriction.

```
public static U To<T, U>(this T self, Func<T, U> eval)
    => eval?.Invoke(self) ?? default(U);
    // => eval == null ? default(U) : eval(self);
```

> Operator '?' cannot be applied to operand of type 'U'

@duplicate

Don't think this is a duplicate, of that one anyways. Im coalescing the func, not the generic type and getting the error on the coalesc (?) not null conditional operator (??) as in the other question.

Comment: Because a class is nullable ('eval?' can work). I meant to say that 'contraints' do not seem to offer a way to specify that 'struct' can now be nullable.

Comment: The type `U` can be a value type and they cannot be used with the null coalescing operator (`?`) or the null conditional operator (`??`). (Note this was answered and deleted for some reason). To fix it you can add the `where U : class` constraint on the method.

Comment: @DavidG Well im coalescing the func `eval` and `=> eval?.Invoke(self) ?? eval(self);` (idiot statement but removes U)  gives the same error..? As I sad adding the constraint limits the monad.